# Why is the image not displaying

Tags: php, html, image

I have the webserver and the sql server working fin but when i run the file no image is displayed and characters like �})>�}(���>��j|��0�Ry>�s appear instead. What am i missing? the cobe below is part of the page.

```
    <body>
         <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $passw = "Ajax3617";
    $dbname="sailingdb";
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $user, $passw, $dbname);

    $sql = "SELECT picturefile FROM pictures";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  {

echo '<img src="'.$row['picturefile'].'" width="175" height="200" />';

    } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check what returned in $row['picturefile']: `var_dump($row['picturefile']);`

Comment: this text onscreen after css is applied     "; var_dump($row['picturefile']); } ?>

Comment: *"when i run the file no image is displayed and the characters `} ?>` appear instead"* - sounds like php's not getting parsed.

Comment: you're also using the wrong connection variable for the query, that should be the connection and not the db, so your code failed for a few reasons.

Comment: and the quoting's wrong `<img src="'.$row['picturefile']."'`

Comment: changed the variable to $conn and the quoting but the same text is appearing any idea what could be preventing parsing?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<img src="'.$row['picturefile']."' >";
```

should be replaced by

```
echo '<img src="'.$row['picturefile'].'" >';
```